# Multiple keypress doesn't work up left and space?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a strange problem when I press up left arrows and space simultaneously. Why doesn't the space work?  I tried to test here http://jsfiddle.net/vor0nwe/mkHsU/ and there is the same problem, you can try!  if you press up , left arrows and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> it works! With left +up + <kbd>g</kbd> no! This happens in Firefox, Chrome etc... why?

Most likely the fault is of the keyboard (see correct answer)! I Tried to press left  (hold) and right shift (hold) and <kbd>x</kbd> in a text document. <kbd>x</kbd> doesn't appear. http://xahlee.blogspot.it/2010/06/keyboard-key-ghosting.html. My keyboard is logitech 200 :-(

Comment: its working for me browser : Chrome Version 24.0.1290.1 dev-m, OS :win 8

Comment: keycode 37 (hold) + 38 (hold) + 32? for me no! chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m win7 :-(

Comment: Works fine for me in Google Chrome 24.0.1297.0 dev under Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually probably your keyboard, it's a phenomenon called "Key Ghosting", certain key combinations wont work on some keyboards.

Comment: +1. I was just about to mention this.  Some keyboards also won't register a third keypress if you've held two keys down for a certain amount of time (usually in milliseconds).

Comment: only on some keycode? ah ok centain key! thanks my keyboard is logitech-classic-200